# Page jumps abit up when an element above fades in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 elements, the first one (at the top) has the following CSS properties:

```
header {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: black;
}
```

This makes it in the size of the browser's viewport, what I did on purpose because I wanted that result. I also had to give the `html, body` element the CSS property's for this to work (filling the screen with the first element):

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

The second element I have looks like this:

```
#content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100%;  
    
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This element is underneath the first one.

As you can see, this element is hidden. That's because when I click on the button on the first element ([which you can see in the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7PD7/8/)) it shows  the `#content` element, scrolls to that, and hides the element where we came from (`header`) when it's done scrolling.

Which works perfectly, I've got the function here:

```
var showScrollHide = function(showTime, element, eleTime, hide, hideTime, func) {
    var _ele = $(element),
        _hide = $(hide);
    _ele.fadeIn(showTime, function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: _ele.offset().top
        }, eleTime, function() {
            _hide.fadeOut(hideTime, func ? func : null);
        });
    });
};
```

I'm calling that function by this piece of code:

```
$('.exploreBtn').on('click', function() {
    showScrollHide(500, content, 1000, header, 250, function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        $('.scrollBackBtn').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

In the snippet above I had to call `$(window).scrollTop(0);` otherwise it would scroll down the page a bit when it was done scrolling. Also I displayed the scroll back button now, but that is the problem.

When I'm on the second element, and the element above it is hidden by the function above. And I try to use the same function to scroll it back up which means:

- Show the element above
- Scroll to it
- Fade out the element we came from

It only gives me a fade to the element I'm trying to scroll to.

When I removed all the code from the function, and only used this:

```
$('header').fadeIn();
```

It just did the same and automatically faded the screen to that element we have just faded in. Which means it scrolls up, but not with any animation or what so ever.

[Here is a jsFiddle to show what I'm doing](http://jsfiddle.net/N7PD7/8/)

**Btw, I already fixed this issue with the help of @Loktar with this piece of code, but I'm still not sure if its the right way to do it:**

```
$('.scrollBackBtn').on('click', function() {
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
    $(header).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Show your code, it's a much better description than a paragraph

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N7PD7/ srry, forgot. The idea is to make it scroll back the same way as it goes down. @JuanMendes

Comment: Please edit your question to include the fiddle. Comments are easily lost, buried.

Comment: Excellent, let's hope that stops a few down votes.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Haha, i'm not very good at this. Do you know how i can prevent the scroll up when i fade a element in action?

Comment: @Dreiba You've already asked the question and ScottMcGready knows, please don't spam. I'm having a hard time figuring out what the problem is. Can you add clear steps (click on green button, see screen turn yellow...) to reproduce including expected and actual behavior?

Comment: @JuanMendes The problem is that when i fade a hidden element in. And is above a element where im currently at. My scroll position jumps up. and i want to prevent that

Comment: @Dreiba I know you're new, but you have to improve your question. Not add new comments. Your question is poorly asked, I'm giving you suggestions on what you need to do to improve your question. Remember SO is not meant to only help you. Your question is supposed to be useful in the future.

Comment: @JuanMendes Your right, i improved my question with the same thing i put here in the comments, is that clear? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: It's still not very clear. When a problem is tricky to explain, you shuld use a bullet list with steps that say `1. click on blue dot, 2. Screen will turn blue and scroll back to the top, 3. Click on blue dot - **Actual behavior**: window scrolls backs to the top. **Expected behavior**: window does not scroll ` It may look the same to you, but to someone who is trying to follow what you mean, it's much clearer

Comment: I don't see what you are saying. Before I click the gray dot on the black background, the page is already scrolled to the top (because you told it to calling `window.scrollTop(0)`, so after clicking it, it's still scrolled all the way up. I still don't understand the problem

Comment: @JuanMendes lol I had the same issue he came into the HTML/CSS/Webdev chat and explained a bit and we helped him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding it correctly the following should work.

```
_scrollBackBtn.on('click', function() {
     _window.scrollTop(0);
    $(header).slideDown();
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/N7PD7/3/)**

Comment: Looks interesting, I can't tell if it's what the OP wanted from the question, but there's a good chance

Comment: Indeed! :D Thank you, but can i give the scroll back up a delay or isnt that possible? and when its back at the top, hide the #content element again?

Comment: @JuanMendes I cheated, he came into the SO Chat and I was able to help him

Comment: @JuanMendes http://jsfiddle.net/N7PD7/4/ I'm trying to do something like that jsFiddle, is that still a correct way to do it? Or is it better to do it with a function?

Comment: @Loktar Good man, it was hard to understand the question. Maybe you'll be so kind to edit the question so I can learn something?

Comment: @Dreiba Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by is it better to do "it" with a function. Try to stay away from `this, it, that, those` when asking a question. Describe what "it" is

Comment: @JuanMendes I would but it would be a rather large edit. What I gathered is he wanted the element to slide in and out basically and for the page to scroll to the top when the element was sliding in.